# Change from ArrayList to Vector

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

I'm working on an android game and I just noticed that since `onTouchEvent` runs on the UI thread, and the update/render methods are ran from a separate threads, both of them  update an `ArrayList` which contains the entities. So obviously they conflict if they happen to modify the list at the same time.

I read that `Vector` class is used exactly the same as `ArrayList` with the only difference that `Vector` is synchronized, ergo they wont conflict. Is that true? if so, does it have any performance issue or something that I should be concerned about? I have never used `Vector` class before.

EDIT: 
what I actually meant was change from

`ArrayList<Obj> list = new ArrayList<Obj>();`

to

`Vector<Obj> list = new Vector<Obj>()`

But as the answers say, `Vector` is not recommended to use. The selected answer solved my issue.

Comment: `Vector` is deprecated, so you should not use it

Comment: Technically it's not, but really it's an ancient and depending on the use case a `List` from the `Concurrent` package is probably going to be better.

Comment: Jon Skeet explains why not to use Vector here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's oldie `Vector` try to not use Vector instead use

[`synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Example :

```
list = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
```

Vector is considered obsolete and deprecated read [Why vector is considerer obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Comment: This solves it: `List<Obj> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Obj>());`

Comment: yep , you got it ;) read Jon Skeet answer in the link i post, is interesting :)

Comment: Yep, it's pretty interesting. It actually helped me a little to understand about the `synchronized` block. I'm kinda new to it (:

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco in the other link synchronizedList if you read says that if you want to iterate the collection you should put synchronized the block

Comment: exactly, basically to iterate the list I put everything into `synchronized(list) { //code }`. By the way, can I iterate the list using a `for()` loop? or do I HAVE to use the iterator class ?

Comment: i think is the same is just the syntaxis, semantics is the same, behind has an iterator the `for()`, try and error :D

Comment: I'll go with the `for()` :D

Answer (score 40):

For those who have to fight with legacy code do just the following:

```
new Vector<Obj>(anyThingWhichImplemntsCollection);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Foo> list = new Vector<Foo>(new ArrayList<Foo>());
```

should work. Both of those structures implements List interface.

But like other people suggested, this is not recomended.

Comment: That code snippet doesn't make much sense. It would add the elements from an empty `ArrayList` to the created `Vector` instance.

Comment: As much as I understood this was what Christopher Francisco asked for. Vector with data from ArrayList. New Array List is there only a kind of mock.

Comment: When using a legacy library which accepts Vector one have to convert List to Vector and this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by nachokk, `synchonizedList` will do the trick.
`synchronizedList` will return a wrapper around your list, so no copying is done.
The downside is that only one call to the list can be done at a time. Two reads at the list will be sequential even if they could be done in parallel. Synchronized blocks always means a little overhead and decreaces performance if called often.

Another option would be to use a concurrent list. This means a copy in the first place, but access performance could be dramatically improved. 
If you have many read requests (e.g. for paintings), a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` will be a good choice. Reads are nearly as fast as a normal ArrayList and won't be blocked. Writes to the list will be sequential and expensive, since they have to copy the whole array.
Another good point for the CoWArrayList is that you can iterate without catching a ConcurrentModificationException. The Iterator returned by `iterator()` will always use the same backing array, even if the list has changed.